# Error: stat_count() can only have an x or y aesthetic

Tags: r

I am getting Error: stat_count() can only have an x or y aesthetic. when trying to plot using data from an excel sheet

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
dataset= read_excel("D:/Downloads/Covid19.xlsx")
dataset2= read_excel("D:/Downloads/Covid19.xlsx", sheet = "Sheet2")
dataset3= dataset[,c(4,5)]
ggplot(dataset2, aes(x=Region, y= male))+geom_bar()
```

My Data from excel file looks like this
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaw7B.png)

[Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmsiU.png)

Comment: or maybe `geom_col`

Comment: @sahwahn it worked

Comment: what if i wanted to add male and female values both inside the graph? @sahwahn

Comment: you'd need to reformat the data into long format - this should explain it https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/48-grouped-barplot-with-ggplot2.html

Comment: @sahwahn is there a simple easy way for an beginner? it went all bouncer for me

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You need to include `stat='identity'`, which is basically telling ggplot2 you will provide the y-values for the barplot, rather than counting the aggregate number of rows for each x value, which is the default `stat=count`

```
ggplot(dataset2, aes(x=Region, y= male)) +
     geom_bar(stat='identity')
```